# Speed difference in open3D using Python and C++

Tags: python, c++, open3d

I'm working on a project where Open3D is highly used. I started by writing the entire code in python to easily test different approaches. However, I have now decided that it is time to write the code in c++, as this is the desire at my workplace. I have managed to implement the same functionality in c++ but it seems like the code is now running much slower than in python. For some specific functions it seems almost 10x slower.

```
frameCounter = 0
while True:
    profile, depth_frame, color_frame = getCamFrames(pipeline_1, align)
    profile2, depth_frame2, color_frame2 = getCamFrames(pipeline_2, align)
    profile3, depth_frame3, color_frame3 = getCamFrames(pipeline_3, align)

    if not depth_frame or not color_frame or not depth_frame2 or not color_frame2 or not depth_frame3 or not color_frame3:
        continue

    img_color, img_depth = imgToNumpy(depth_frame, color_frame)
    img_color2, img_depth2 = imgToNumpy(depth_frame2, color_frame2)
    img_color3, img_depth3 = imgToNumpy(depth_frame3, color_frame3)

    rgbd = o3d.geometry.RGBDImage.create_from_color_and_depth(img_color, img_depth, convert_rgb_to_intensity=False, depth_trunc=1.2)
    rgbd2 = o3d.geometry.RGBDImage.create_from_color_and_depth(img_color2, img_depth2, convert_rgb_to_intensity=False, depth_trunc=1.2)
    rgbd3 = o3d.geometry.RGBDImage.create_from_color_and_depth(img_color3, img_depth3, convert_rgb_to_intensity=False, depth_trunc=1.6)

    intrinsics, pinhole_camera_intrinsic = getCamInfo(profile)
    intrinsics2, pinhole_camera_intrinsic2 = getCamInfo(profile2)
    intrinsics3, pinhole_camera_intrinsic3 = getCamInfo(profile3)

    volume.integrate(rgbd, pinhole_camera_intrinsic, rob_cam1)
    volume2.integrate(rgbd2, pinhole_camera_intrinsic2, rob_cam2)
    volume3.integrate(rgbd3, pinhole_camera_intrinsic3, rob_cam3)

    if frameCounter == 10:
        volume.reset()
        volume2.reset()
        volume3.reset()

    frameCounter += 1

    if frameCounter == 30:
        GenerateCroppedMesh(volume, volume2, volume3)
        pipeline_1.stop()
        pipeline_2.stop()
        pipeline_3.stop()
        break
```

The same functionality implemented in c++:

```
    void open3dStuff(const sensor_data& sensor_1, const sensor_data& sensor_2, const sensor_data& sensor_3,
    cv::Mat trans_501, cv::Mat trans_309, cv::Mat trans_699, open3d::camera::PinholeCameraIntrinsic intrics_1,
    open3d::camera::PinholeCameraIntrinsic intrics_2, open3d::camera::PinholeCameraIntrinsic intrics_3) {

    open3d::pipelines::integration::ScalableTSDFVolume* volume1 = new open3d::pipelines::integration::ScalableTSDFVolume(
        4.0 / 512.0, 0.02, open3d::pipelines::integration::TSDFVolumeColorType::RGB8);

    open3d::pipelines::integration::ScalableTSDFVolume* volume2 = new open3d::pipelines::integration::ScalableTSDFVolume(
        4.0 / 512.0, 0.02, open3d::pipelines::integration::TSDFVolumeColorType::RGB8);

    open3d::pipelines::integration::ScalableTSDFVolume* volume3 = new open3d::pipelines::integration::ScalableTSDFVolume(
        4.0 / 512.0, 0.01, open3d::pipelines::integration::TSDFVolumeColorType::RGB8);

    using legacyRGBDImage = open3d::t::geometry::RGBDImage;
    using legacyImage = open3d::geometry::RGBDImage;

    Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> eigen_501;
    Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> eigen_309;
    Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> eigen_699;

    cv::cv2eigen(trans_501, eigen_501);
    cv::cv2eigen(trans_309, eigen_309);
    cv::cv2eigen(trans_699, eigen_699);

    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < 30)
    {
        legacyRGBDImage rgbd_1 = update_data(sensor_1.depth_data, sensor_1.color_data);
        legacyRGBDImage rgbd_2 = update_data(sensor_2.depth_data, sensor_2.color_data);
        legacyRGBDImage rgbd_3 = update_data(sensor_3.depth_data, sensor_3.color_data);

        if (rgbd_1.IsEmpty() || rgbd_2.IsEmpty() || rgbd_3.IsEmpty())
        {
            continue;
        }

        std::cout << counter << "\n" << std::endl;

        legacyImage im_1 = rgbd_1.ToLegacy();
        legacyImage im_2 = rgbd_2.ToLegacy();
        legacyImage im_3 = rgbd_3.ToLegacy();

        std::shared_ptr<open3d::geometry::RGBDImage> o3d_rgbd_1 = open3d::geometry::RGBDImage::CreateFromColorAndDepth(im_1.color_, im_1.depth_, 1000.0, 1.2, false);
        std::shared_ptr<open3d::geometry::RGBDImage> o3d_rgbd_2 = open3d::geometry::RGBDImage::CreateFromColorAndDepth(im_2.color_, im_2.depth_, 1000.0, 1.2, false);
        std::shared_ptr<open3d::geometry::RGBDImage> o3d_rgbd_3 = open3d::geometry::RGBDImage::CreateFromColorAndDepth(im_3.color_, im_3.depth_, 1000.0, 1.6, false);

        if (counter == 10) {
            volume1->Reset();
            volume2->Reset();
            volume3->Reset();
        }

        volume1->Integrate(*o3d_rgbd_1, intrics_1, eigen_501);
        volume2->Integrate(*o3d_rgbd_2, intrics_2, eigen_309);
        volume3->Integrate(*o3d_rgbd_3, intrics_3, eigen_699);

        counter++;
    }
}
```

I have made sure to use same framerate, resolution and so on, for both codes.

Later on I also use the RegistrationICP() function, and here there seems to be a huge difference in running time again.
I anyone knows something, please let me know :)

Comment: How did you compile the C++-version?

Comment: @churill I am using c++ 14 - Legacy MSVC

Comment: Are you using an optimised build?

Comment: @AlanBirtles no that is not turned on.

Comment: @Eljay I believe i already wrote that in the question. I have not made a timer in the code but simply timed it with my phone and it seems to be around 10x slower :)

Comment: Measuring the performance of unoptimised c++ code is fairly pointless, optimised code is usually significantly faster

Comment: @mikkelsen1996 Indeed most questions like this end with "use an optimized build", apparently many people don't know this. In one of my university-project for computer-graphics the release build was about 30 times faster than the debug-build. That's how C++ works, horribly slow debug builds, but blazing fast when optimized.

Comment: @churill okay I will try in release, and make sure to use "optimized build". I will let you know if the performance changes :)

Comment: @churill sorry for the long wait. I have tried to run the code in release now and it is true that it runs a lot faster than in debug. The total runniing time is now around 11 seconds wheras it was approximately 40 seconds beforehand. However, this is still not as fast as in python as the running time here is around 4-5 seconds. I think this is because Open3d has optimized the code in the functiions calls in python greatly. Maybe I will achieve the same speed later in the project. Thanks a lot for the help.